# Renaming similar columns from different DataFrames using for loop and Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, for-loop

Today I've been working with five DataFrames that are almost the same, but for different courses. They are named `df2b2015`, `df4b2015`, `df6b2015`, `df2m2015`.

Every one of those DataFrames has a column named `prom_lect2b_rbd` for `df2b2015`, `prom_lect4b_rbd` for `df4b2015`, and so on.

I want to append those DataFrames, but because every column has a different name, they don't go together. I'm trying to turn every one of those columns into a `prom_lect_rbd` column, so I can then  append them without problem.

Is there a way I can do that with a `for` loop and `regex`. 
Else, is there a way I can do it with other means?

Thanks!

PS: I know some things, like I can turn the columns into what I want using:

```
re.sub('\d(b|m)','', a)
```

Where `a` is the columns name. But I can't find a way to mix that with loops and column renaming.

Edit:

DataFrame(s) look like this:

df2b2015:

```
rbd   prom_lect2b_rbd
 1          5
 2          6
```

df4b2015:

```
rbd   prom_lect4b_rbd
 1          8
 2          9
```

etc.

Comment: Good news is, there is a way!  However, you're far more likely to get someone to help you if you provide sample data and expected results.  Read [mcve].  That said, all you need is to show 2 dataframes with 2 rows each and the appropriate column names.  State that it needs to be a general solution to accommodate more than 2 dataframes.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I'll Edit it if someone has a better answer than mine !

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it. Probably not the most Pythonic way, but it does what I wanted:

```
dfs=[df2b2015,df4b2015,df6b2015,df8b2015,df2m2015]
cols_lect=['prom_lect2b_rbd','prom_lect4b_rbd','prom_lect6b_rbd',
           'prom_lect8b_rbd','prom_lect2m_rbd']

for j,k in zip(dfs,cols_lect):
    j.rename(columns={k:re.sub('\d(b|m)','', k)}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, with `.filter(regex=)`? It does assume there is only one matching column per dataframe but your example permits that.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3),columns=['prom_lect2b_rbd','foo','bar'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3),columns=['prom_lect4b_rbd','foo','bar'])

for df in [df1,df2]:
    colname = df.filter(regex='prom_lect*').columns.format()
    df.rename(columns={colname[0]:'prom_lect_rbd'})

print(df1)
print(df2)
```